cdlatex misbehaves when input methods are present
I've noticed that when using Ibus or Fcitx5, cdlatex won't display the help buffer when the trigger keys ` and ' are pressed. The shortcuts will still work, but I can't see the list of shortcuts that usually appear.
For some reason, this only happens when running with pgtk active, I believe because it being a Wayland native application in this case, it can receive inputs from both IME above. I “fixed” this by adding the English US keyboard layout to the list of layouts I have on Ibus, since I need the US, Intl with Dead Keys layout for my day-to-day usage.
However, it's a bit cumbersome to switch to another input method just to write TeX. So I wonder if this is just some weird behavior and nothing can be done about it, or there is some fix I don't know of.
